# SQL - How to UNION ALL IF @rowcount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query (`SQL SERVER`)

```
SELECT name, number, position, workingyears 
FROM employee 
WHERE type = 'A'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BEGIN

SELECT name, number, position, workingyears 
FROM employee 
WHERE type = 'B'

        END
```

If the result of first select is empty then I need to do other select that is going to have the same columns but different filters. How can I get only one table as a result.

Comment: `The result of this when @@ROWCOUNT = 0 are two tables. How can I UNION ALL?`..Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether `type = 'A'` exists and then use 1st or 2nd query.

```
if exists(select 1 from employee WHERE type = 'A')

SELECT name, number, position, workingyears 
FROM employee 
WHERE type = 'A'

else

SELECT name, number, position, workingyears 
FROM employee 
WHERE type = 'B'
```

Or in a single query.

```
SELECT name, number, position, workingyears 
FROM employee 
WHERE type = case when exists(select 1 from employee WHERE type = 'A') then 'A'
             else 'B' end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT name, number, position, workingyears 
FROM employee 
WHERE type = 'A'

UNION ALL

SELECT name, number, position, workingyears 
FROM employee 
WHERE (type = 'B' and NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM employee WHERE type = 'A'))
```